# Date time comparision not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to comparison date and time between current date to previous, it working on IDE but not from my code. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong!?

The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "read_log.py", line 37, in
>    if log_date < current_time and log_date > lastHourTime :
>   TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str

---

Code from IDE:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print current_time.strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S')
Feb 19 15:45:49
>>> c= current_time.strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S')
>>> lastHourTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
>>> l=lastHourTime.strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print l
Feb 19 14:47:32
>>> print c
Feb 19 15:45:49
>>> print l
Feb 19 14:47:32
>>> l<c
True
>>> l>c
False
>>> m='Feb  7 07:33:19'
>>> m<l
True
>>>
```

My script code :

```
get_date = re.compile('([A-Z-a-z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)(.*)')
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
lastHourTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)


log_file=_read_log()

for line in log_file:

        match=re.search(get_date,line)
        if match:

          log_date= match.group(1).rstrip()

          if  log_date < current_time and log_date > lastHourTime :
                print line
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are comparing string (log_date) with datetime.datetime (current_time).

So i guess you want to convert log_date to datetime:

```
import datetime as dt

d = 'Feb  7 07:33:19'

print(dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %d %H:%M:%S").replace(year=dt.date.today().year))
```

For example:

```
get_date = re.compile('([A-Z-a-z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)(.*)')
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
lastHourTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)


log_file=_read_log()

for line in log_file:

    match=re.search(get_date,line)
    if match:

        log_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(1).rstrip(), "%b %d %H:%M:%S").replace(year=datetime.date.today().year)

        if  log_date < current_time and log_date > lastHourTime :
            print line
```

Comment: Hi MAxu , Here I am trying to compare the time , so if i convert log_date to the out put you provided, dont I need to convert current_time and lastHourTime in the same format as log_date ?

Comment: Hi @alammd, no you need to convert log_date (which is as a string, because of nature of the "re.search().group()" function) to datetime.datetime, as i showed in the answer. then you will compare two datetime.datetime's.

Comment: Hi, Max, there is small issues, some date comparion not working, example  out put of the command , i am usign exactly the command you using ,    only changes is , i am using one clause which is log_date < currentTime.                                                                                        Current Time Feb 20 10:46:21
Log Date 2016-12-13 07:33:11
Not Matching
Dec 13 07:33:11 xxxx  yum[6315]: Installed: 14:tcpdump-4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6.x86_64
Log Date 2016-01-21 15:03:20
Matching
Jan 21 15:03:20 xxxxxyum[6352]: Installed: gnutls-2.8.5-19.el6_7.x86_64

Comment: <pre>                                                                                            Current Time Feb 20 10:46:21
Log Date 2016-12-13 07:33:11
Not Matching
Dec 13 07:33:11 xxxx  yum[6315]: Installed: 14:tcpdump-4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6.x86_64
Log Date 2016-01-21 15:03:20
Matching
Jan 21 15:03:20 xxxxxyum[6352]: Installed: gnutls-2.8.5-19.el6_7.x86_64  <code>

Comment: <pre>                                                                                            Current Time Feb 20 10:46:21 <br/>
Log Date 2016-12-13 07:33:11 <br/>
Not Matching <br/>
Dec 13 07:33:11 xxxx  yum[6315]: Installed: 14:tcpdump-4.0.0-5.20090921gitdf3cb4.2.el6.x86_64 <br/>
Log Date 2016-01-21 15:03:20 <br/>
Matching <br/>
Jan 21 15:03:20 xxxxxyum[6352]: Installed: gnutls-2.8.5-19.el6_7.x86_64  <code>

Comment: @MxU, What i understand is, its not matching any date from Previous year, but dates from this year looks ok, does it make any sense ?

Comment: @alammd, yes it does! Strings like 'Feb  7 07:33:19' do not contain any information about the year. So you you will need to define how do you want to compare dates in this case...